# Combine datasets by date range and categorical variable

Tags: r, performance, for-loop, dplyr

Suppose I have two datasets. One contains a list of promotions with start/end dates, and the other contains monthly sales data for each program.

```
promotions = data.frame(
    start.date = as.Date(c("2012-01-01", "2012-06-14", "2012-02-01", "2012-03-31", "2012-07-13")), 
    end.date = as.Date(c("2014-04-05", "2014-11-13", "2014-02-25", "2014-08-02", "2014-09-30")), 
    program = c("a", "a", "a", "b", "b"))

sales = data.frame(
    year.month.day = as.Date(c("2013-02-01", "2014-09-01", "2013-08-01", "2013-04-01", "2012-11-01")), 
    program = c("a", "b", "a", "a", "b"), 
    monthly.sales = c(200, 200, 200, 400, 200))
```

Note that `sales$year.month.day` is used to indicate year/month. Day is included so R can more simply treat the column as a vector of date objects, but it isn't relevant to the actual sales.

I need to determine the number of promotions that occurred per month for each program. Here's an example of a loop that produces the output I want:

```
sales$count = rep(0, nrow(sales))
sub = list()
for (i in 1:nrow(sales)) {
  sub[[i]] = promotions[which(promotions$program == sales$program[i]),]
  if (nrow(sub[[i]]) > 1) {
    for (j in 1:nrow(sub[[i]])) {
      if (sales$year.month.day[i] %in% seq(from = as.Date(sub[[i]]$start.date[j]), to = as.Date(sub[[i]]$end.date[j]), by = "day")) {
        sales$count[i] = sales$count[i] + 1
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Example output:

```
 sales = data.frame(
    year.month.day = as.Date(c("2013-02-01", "2014-09-01", "2013-08-01", "2013-04-01", "2012-11-01")), 
    program = c("a", "b", "a", "a", "b"), 
    monthly.sales = c(200, 200, 200, 400, 200),
    count = c(3, 1, 3, 3, 2)
)
```

However since my actual datasets are very large, this loop crashes when I run it in R.

Is there a more efficient way to achieve the same result? Perhaps something with dplyr?

Comment: Can you add the desired output data frame? I do not really understand the output of your loop.  Also if you are interested in the number of promotions per month, per program, why do you need the sales data frame?

Comment: I've edited the post to include the output of my loop. The loop adds a "count" column to the original sales data.frame.

Comment: For my analysis I need sales and the number of promotions per month for each program, so yes, the sales data.frame is necessary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am a fan of Hadley's packages:

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
```

Floor dates so they are in the same format as the `sales` dataframe:

```
df <- promotions %>% 
    mutate(start.date = floor_date(start.date, unit = "month"),
           end.date = floor_date(end.date, unit = "month"))
```

Expand the date intervals:

```
df$output <- mapply(function(x,y) seq(x, y, by =  "month"),
       df$start.date,
       df$end.date)
```

Expand the data frame based on the date ranges, group and count, and merge to sales on date and program:

```
df %>% tidyr::unnest(output) %>% 
    group_by(output, program) %>%
    summarise(prom_num = n()) %>%
    merge(sales, ., 
      by.x = c("year.month.day", "program"),
      by.y = c("output", "program"))
```

Output:

```
  year.month.day program monthly.sales prom_num
1     2012-11-01       b           200        2
2     2013-02-01       a           200        3
3     2013-04-01       a           400        3
4     2013-08-01       a           200        3
5     2014-09-01       b           200        1
```

Answer (score 6):

Using the newly implemented *non-equi* joins from the current development version of data.table:

```
require(data.table) # v1.9.7+
setDT(promotions) # convert to data.table by reference
setDT(sales)

ans = promotions[sales, .(monthly.sales, .N), by=.EACHI, allow.cartesian=TRUE, 
        on=.(program, start.date<=year.month.day, end.date>=year.month.day), nomatch=0L]

ans[, end.date := NULL]
setnames(ans, "start.date", "year.month.date")
#    program year.month.date monthly.sales N
# 1:       a      2013-02-01           200 3
# 2:       b      2014-09-01           200 1
# 3:       a      2013-08-01           200 3
# 4:       a      2013-04-01           400 3
# 5:       b      2012-11-01           200 2
```

See installation instructions for development version [here](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Installation).

Answer (score 5):

You can do this with sql.

```
library(sqldf)
sqldf("select s.ymd,p.program,s.monthlysales, count(*) from promotions p outer left join sales s on p.program=s.program 
where s.ymd between p.startdate and p.enddate and p.program=s.program group by s.ymd, s.program" )
```

This would first join the 2 data set where ymd in sales is between the start and end date of promotion and program in both the data are same. then it would group by ymd and count the instance. I have removed the periods from the names of variable.

Comment: this appears to return only one row per ymd. it might be okay for some datasets, but not those that require monthly counts for every categorical variable

Comment: I have edited it so that it will give u as many ymd as there are program.

Answer (score 3):

Could try `?data.table::foverlaps` for that

```
library(data.table)
setDT(sales)[, c("start.date", "end.date") := year.month.day] # Add overlap cols
setkey(sales, program, start.date, end.date) # Key for join
res <- foverlaps(setDT(promotions), sales)[, .N, by = year.month.day] # Count joins
sales[res, count := i.N, on = "year.month.day"] # Update `sales` with results
sales
#    year.month.day program monthly.sales start.date   end.date count
# 1:     2013-02-01       a           200 2013-02-01 2013-02-01     3
# 2:     2013-04-01       a           400 2013-04-01 2013-04-01     3
# 3:     2013-08-01       a           200 2013-08-01 2013-08-01     3
# 4:     2012-11-01       b           200 2012-11-01 2012-11-01     2
# 5:     2014-09-01       b           200 2014-09-01 2014-09-01     1
```

This is basically creates interval column in `sales`, joins by them + by `program`, counts overlaps, and joins back to `sales`. You could remove the additional columns by doing `sales[, c("start.date", "end.date") := NULL]` if it really bothers you. Google `foverlaps` and `data.table` for more examples