# Count number of rows within certain range

Tags: r, dataframe, performance, data.table, range

I have a data.table with some values ('value'), lower limits ('min_val') and upper limits ('max_val'):

```
   | value | min_val | max_val |
1: | 94.001 | 94.00 | 94.02 |
2: | 94.002 | 94.00 | 94.03 |
3: | 94.003 | 94.01 | 94.04 |
4: | 95 | 94.98 | 95.02 |
```

I want to calculate the count of rows where value > min_val & value < max_val for each line for the values from the whole dt.

```
   | value | min_val | max_val | count |
1: | 94.001 | 94.00 | 94.02 |  1       |   #(num of value(s) > 94.00 &  < 94.02)
2: | 94.002 | 94.00 | 94.03 |  2       |
3: | 94.003 | 94.01 | 94.04 |  2       |
4: | 95     | 94.98 | 95.02 |  1       |
```

I've tried
`dt[, count := nrow(dt[value > dt[min_val] & value < dt[max_val]])]` but I'm on the wrong path.

Comment: I think he means count how many rows of the same table have the value in the given range. I also think there is a mistake in the second table, the count for the first line should be 3, and the count for the third line should be 0.

Comment: I see now .....

Comment: `d[ , N := d[d, on = .(value > min_val, value < max_val), .N, by = .EACHI]$N]`

Comment: @Henrik You should consider as=dding that as a solution

Comment: Try the code given above

Comment: Henrik's solution is executing since ~2h. I'll fill in details when/if the method completes. Memory utilization is low 12GB/768.

Comment: Henrik's solution is still executing (24h+ now). I've stopped all others and in parallel started executing another solution that I've developed. `count_tol <- function(v, vmin, vmax) {
  output <- length(v)
  for (i in 1:length(v)) {
    output[i] <- length(which(v > vmin[i] & v > vmax[i]))
  }
  return(output)
}
dt[, count := count_tol(dt[, value], dt[, min_val], dt[, max_val])]`

Comment: thanks Henrik's the code actually finished execution :)

Comment: @Henrik what if I need to add another condition that I would normally add into a by?

Comment: tried by= .(EACHI, <FilterColumn>) but got Join results in more than 2^31 rows (internal vecseq reached physical limit). Very likely misspecified join. Check for duplicate key values in i each of which join to the same group in x over and over again. If that's ok, try by=.EACHI to run j for each group to avoid the large allocation. Otherwise, please search for this error message in the FAQ, Wiki, Stack Overflow and data.table issue tracker for advice.

Comment: Hi @iuliux! Sorry, but it is hard to understand your context. Perhaps you intend to add "another condition" in `on`, like e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38664059/1851712)?

Comment: @Henrik exactly, now the condition is value > min_val, value < max_val, now I want to add a constrain, do the same where the values from another column (Temperature) are the same. So I did d[ , N := d[d, on = .(value > min_val, value < max_val, Temperature), .N, by = .EACHI]$N] and now R is crashing :) (R encountered a fatal error). I'll try to update

Comment: I strongly recommend to begin with a truly _minimal_ toy data set that you can play around with, and easily track every single match in the join and to follow the logic. Then you can try on larger data. Here's [an excellent tutorial on data.table joins](http://franknarf1.github.io/r-tutorial/_book/tables.html#dt-joins), including examples on non-equi and `.EACHI`. Good luck!

Comment: @Henrik thanks a lot. btw, please add your original response as a solution so I can accept it. maybe there are others that are bumping into the same issues.

Comment: @iuliux Well, it seems like Uwe has already nicely described my suggestion, so I'm a bit reluctant to add an answer. That said, feel free to write up an answer if you want! BTW, I note that you already have received [a nice equi + non-equi / `.EACHI` / `.N` answer on your previous Q](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59601279/1851712) ;)

Answer (score 8):

The [OP has disclosed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68958126/can-i-count-number-of-rows-within-certain-values/68958336#comment121871270_68958336) that his production dataset consists of 81 million rows. Unfortunately,  [r2evans' benchmark](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68958336/3817004) used only the 4 rows sample dataset provided with the question and has neglected [henrik's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68958126/can-i-count-number-of-rows-within-certain-values/68958336#comment121872436_68958126). To find the best approach for a large dataset like OP's one I find it worthwhile to run benchmarks with *varying and realistic problem sizes* in order to measure *run time* as well as *memory consumption*.

Run time and memory consumption may be depend on

1. the number of values,
2. the number of intervals,
3. and the number of values which fall into each interval.

Items 1 and 2 are linked as the number of values and the number of intervals is given by the number of rows in the dataset. So, there are two size parameter we can vary, the number of rows `n` and the number values within each interval `m`. In order to have reproducible and predictable benchmark data, the benchmark datasets are constructed by

```
d <- data.table(value = as.double(seq(n)))[, min_val := value - m][, max_val := value + m][, count := -1L]
```

In case of `n <- 4` and `m <- 1` `d` becomes

```
   value min_val max_val count
   <num>   <num>   <num> <int>
1:     1       0       2    -1
2:     2       1       3    -1
3:     3       2       4    -1
4:     4       3       5    -1
```

In order to create equal conditions for each benchmark run the `count` column is pre-allocated with some dummy data.

The benchmark includes

- [henrik's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68958126/can-i-count-number-of-rows-within-certain-values/68958336#comment121872436_68958126) to *aggregate in a non-equi self join*,
- the 3 approaches in [r2evans' 3 answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68958336/3817004),
- the [answer by ThomasIsCoding](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68958533/3817004),
- the [answer by Alexandre Léonard](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68958423/3817004)

**Edit:** A 3rd set of benchmark runs compares

- [henrik's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68958126/can-i-count-number-of-rows-within-certain-values/68958336#comment121872436_68958126) *aggregate in a non-equi self join*, and
- [chinsoon12's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68981787/3817004) *Rcpp* solution.

Unfortunately, [TarJae's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68958792/3817004) did not work for me.

```
library(data.table)
library(bench)
library(ggplot2)
options(datatable.print.class = TRUE)

bm1 <- press(
  n = 2^c(2, 10, 13),
  m = 2^c(0, 9, 12),
  {
    d <- data.table(value = as.double(seq(n)))[, min_val := value - m][, max_val := value + m][, count := -1L]
    mark(
      henrik = {
        d[ , count := d[d, on = .(value > min_val, value < max_val), .N, by = .EACHI]$N]
      },
      r2evans0 = {
        d[, count := rowSums(outer(seq_len(.N), value, function(i, v) {min_val[i] < v & v < max_val[i];}))]
      },
      r2evans1 = {
        d[, count := mapply(function(mi,ma) sum(mi < value & value < ma), min_val, max_val)]
      },
      r2evans2 = {
        d[, count := rowSums(outer(min_val, d$value, `<`) &
                               outer(max_val, d$value, `>`)),
          by = .(g = seq_len(nrow(d)) %/% 100)]
      },
      Thomas = {
        d[, count := colSums(outer(value, min_val, ">") & outer(value, max_val, "<"))]
      },
      Alexandre = {
        d[, count := lapply(
          # seq.int(1, nrow(d)),
          seq_len(nrow(d)),
          function(i) sum(d[, value] > d[i, min_val] & d[, value] < d[i, max_val])
        )]
      },
      min_iterations = 3
    )
  }
)

autoplot(bm1)
```

[image]

Please, note the logarithmic time scale.

The chart exhibits that

- Alexandre's approach is up to a magnitude slower than any of the other solutions (and may be omitted from further runs),
- with increasing number of rows `n` henrik's approach becomes neck and neck with `r2evans1` (worth to be investigated further),
- the number of values in each interval `m` seems to have no or little effect on run time.

The latter can be verified by changing the facets and plotting the median times for different `m` in one facet:

```
ggplot(bm1) +
  aes(x = median, y = expression, color = as.factor(m)) +
  geom_point() + 
  facet_wrap(vars(n))
```

[image]

In the next chart below, plotting `mem_alloc` instead of `median` times exhibits that

- `m` has no effect on memory allocation (with one exception),
- for large `n`, henrik's approach needs magnitudes less memory than any other approach:

[image]

Please, note the log scale.

#### 2nd set of benchmark runs

Based on the previous results, the next set of benchmark runs varies only size parameter `n` while `m` is kept constant. Alexandre's approach is omitted as it is too slow.

`n` is varied from `2^10` (1024) to `2^14` (16384) with `m = 1.0`. Unfortunately, the run with `n = 2^15` was aborted due to lack of memory on my PC.

```
autoplot(bm2)
```

[image]

henrik's approach has taken lead in terms of speed for the `2^14` (16384) rows case.

To identify if this indicates a trend, run time vs problem size `n` is plotted by

```
ggplot(bm2) + 
  aes(x = n, y = median, color = expression, group = attr(expression, "description"), 
      label = ifelse(n == max(n), attr(expression, "description"), "")) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth(method = "lm", se = FALSE) +
  scale_x_continuous(trans = scales::log2_trans(), expand = expansion(mult = c(0.05, 0.1))) + 
  ggrepel::geom_label_repel(direction = "y", nudge_x = 1000)
```

[image]

henrik's approach seems to have a high overhead but gains a speed advantage with increasing problem size.

Also with respect to memory allocation, henrik's approach *aggregating in a non-equi self join* seems to need substantially less memory than the other approaches. More importantly, memory allocation increases less steep with problem size which indicates that this approach can handle much larger problem sizes when available computer memory is a limiting factor.

[image]

#### EDIT: 3rd set of benchmark runs

This set of benchmark runs compares [henrik's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68958126/can-i-count-number-of-rows-within-certain-values/68958336#comment121872436_68958126) *aggregate in a non-equi self join* with [chinsoon12's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68981787/3817004) new *Rcpp* solution.

Due to the much smaller memory footprint of both approaches the problem size can be increased up to `2^18` (262144) rows before hitting the *16 GB memory limit on my Windows PC*.

```
library(Rcpp)
bm4 <- press(
  n = 2^(10:18),
  {
    m <- 1.
    d <- data.table(value = as.double(seq(n)))[, min_val := value - m][, max_val := value + m][, count := -1L]
    mark(
      henrik = {
        d[ , count := d[d, on = .(value > min_val, value < max_val), .N, by = .EACHI]$N]
      },
      chinsoon = {
        cppFunction("IntegerVector inrange(NumericVector v, NumericVector minv, NumericVector maxv) {
    int n = v.size();
    IntegerVector res(n);
    
    for (int r=0; r<n; r++) {
        for (int i=0; i<n; i++) {
            if (v[i] > minv[r] && v[i] < maxv[r]) {
                res[r]++;
            }
        }
    }
    
    return res;
}")
        d[, count := inrange(value, min_val, max_val)]
      },
      min_iterations = 3
    )
  }
)
```

The next two charts show the median run time and the memory allocation vs problem size, resp. (please, note the log scales):

[image]

[image]

Results for `n = 2^18` (262144):

```
setDT(bm4)[n == 2^18, .(expression = unique(attr(expression, "description")), 
                        n, median, mem_alloc)]
```

> ```
>    expression      n       median     mem_alloc
>        <char>  <num> <bench_time> <bench_bytes>
> 1:     henrik 262144       17.47s       12.14MB
> 2:   chinsoon 262144        1.03m        2.06MB
> ```

Apparently, chinsoon's approach is faster for problem sizes up to `2^16` (65536) while henrik's approach ist faster for larger problem sizes (and seems to have a more linear time behaviour). For problem size `n = 2^18`, henrik's approach is almost 4 times faster than chinsoon's.

On the other hand, henrik's approach allocates much more memory than chinsoon's. For problem size `n = 2^18`, henrik's approach allocates about 6 time more memory than chinsoon's. Apparently, this ratio is constant for increasing problem size.

So, there is a tradeoff between speed (henrik's approach) and memory requirement (chinsoon's approach) depending on problem size. Your mileage may vary.

Comment: Very interesting analysis, Uwe! Thanks for doing all of that work.

Comment: Comprehensive benchmarking, cool! Upvoted for your excellent efforts!

Comment: thanks, Uwe. Do you know if `bench::press` compiles the cpp function each time in the benchmarking?

Answer (score 5):

We can try `outer` like this

```
> setDT(df)[, count := colSums(outer(value, min_val, ">") & outer(value, max_val, "<"))][]
    value min_val max_val count
1: 94.001   94.00   94.02     3
2: 94.002   94.00   94.03     3
3: 94.003   94.01   94.04     0
4: 95.000   94.98   95.02     1
```

## data

```
> dput(df)
structure(list(value = c(94.001, 94.002, 94.003, 95), min_val = c(94,
94, 94.01, 94.98), max_val = c(94.02, 94.03, 94.04, 95.02)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,
-4L))
```

Comment: thanks for hint with outer, still getting Error in rep(Y, rep.int(length(X), length(Y))) : invalid 'times' argument

Answer (score 4):

**Edit**, with 23M rows, you'll need a slightly different strategy. Original answer kept below this.

For much larger datasets, `outer` (by itself) is not a safe method. Two alternative approaches, both of which will be slower (but that is the tradeoff you must make if you are memory-constrained):

1. Line-by-line (of `min_val` and `max_val`); this is the simpler of the two, while giving the desired results.

   ```r
   dat[, count := mapply(function(mi,ma) sum(mi < value & value < ma), min_val, max_val)]
   #    value min_val max_val count
   #    <num>   <num>   <num> <int>
   # 1: 94.01   94.00   94.02     1
   # 2: 94.02   94.00   94.03     2
   # 3: 94.03   94.01   94.04     2
   # 4: 95.00   94.98   95.02     1
   ```
2. Faster (and borrowing from ThomasIsCoding's method), grouped, but a little more complicated. Effectively using `outer` on `n` rows at a time.

   ```r
   dat[, count := rowSums(outer(min_val, dat$value, `<`) &
                            outer(max_val, dat$value, `>`)),
       by = .(g = seq_len(nrow(dat)) %/% 100)]
   ```

   In this example, we're working on 100 rows at a time for the `*_val` variables, and the whole `value` column which we saved externally as `ovalue`. (You may need to play around to find the best value instead of 100: you'll know when you go too high.)

---

Original solution provided:

```r
dat[, count := rowSums(outer(seq_len(.N), value, function(i, v) min_val[i] < v & v < max_val[i]))]
#    value min_val max_val count
#    <num>   <num>   <num> <num>
# 1: 94.01   94.00   94.02     1
# 2: 94.02   94.00   94.03     2
# 3: 94.03   94.01   94.04     2
# 4: 95.00   94.98   95.02     1
```

Quick walk-through:

- `outer(.,.,.)` does an outer-product, where we look at every row-index (`seq_len(.N)`) against every `value`; the reason we need to compare against the row indices is that we need both `min_val` and `max_val`, and that isn't easy with a two-argument function;
- the function we give to `outer` is called *once*, with two vectors:

  ```r
  cbind(i, v)
  #       i      v
  #  [1,] 1 94.001
  #  [2,] 2 94.001
  #  [3,] 3 94.001
  #  [4,] 4 94.001
  #  [5,] 1 94.002
  #  [6,] 2 94.002
  #  [7,] 3 94.002
  #  [8,] 4 94.002
  #  [9,] 1 94.003
  # [10,] 2 94.003
  # [11,] 3 94.003
  # [12,] 4 94.003
  # [13,] 1 95.000
  # [14,] 2 95.000
  # [15,] 3 95.000
  # [16,] 4 95.000
  ```

  This works fine for us, because `min_val[i]` produces 16 numbers, same with `max_val`, and `v` is already the numbers we want to compare.
- the `outer(.)` returns a matrix:

  ```r
  # dat[, outer(seq_len(.N), value, function(i, v) min_val[i] < v & v < max_val[i])]
  # #       [,1]  [,2]  [,3]  [,4]
  # # [1,]  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
  # # [2,]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
  # # [3,] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
  # # [4,] FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
  ```

  where each column in row 1 represents a *row* that matches row 1's `min_val` and `max_val` constraints. For that, then, we just need to `rowSums` the matrix to get our 1, 2, 2, and 1.

Note: based on your comments and expected output, I believe your `value` should really be `94.01` and not `94.001` (etc).

---

### Data

```r
dat <- setDT(structure(list(value = c(94.01, 94.02, 94.03, 95), min_val = c(94, 94, 94.01, 94.98), max_val = c(94.02, 94.03, 94.04, 95.02)), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -4L)))
```

---

### Benchmarks

(Honestly, I was expecting ThomasIsCoding's double-`outer` to have *some* penalty, but apparently not. My guess is that my indirection using `i` is just as barely-noticeable as a double-`outer`.)

```r
bench::mark(
  r2evans = dat[, count := rowSums(outer(seq_len(.N), value, function(i, v) {min_val[i] < v & v < max_val[i];}))],
  ThomasIsCoding = dat[, count := colSums(outer(value, min_val, ">") & outer(value, max_val, "<"))],
  AlexandreLeonard = dat[, 
    count := lapply(seq.int(1, nrow(dt)), function(i) {
      sum(dt[, value] > dt[i, min_val] & dt[, value] < dt[i, max_val])
    })]
)
# # A tibble: 3 x 13
#   expression            min   median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec` n_itr  n_gc total_time result    memory    time   gc     
#   <bch:expr>       <bch:tm> <bch:tm>     <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl> <int> <dbl>   <bch:tm> <list>    <list>    <list> <list> 
# 1 r2evans           319.3us  347.7us     2449.      33KB     4.24  1154     2      471ms <data.ta~ <Rprofme~ <bch:~ <tibbl~
# 2 ThomasIsCoding    301.5us 344.05us     2454.    32.6KB     2.05  1196     1      487ms <data.ta~ <Rprofme~ <bch:~ <tibbl~
# 3 AlexandreLeonard   3.77ms   4.44ms      205.   408.8KB     4.31    95     2      464ms <data.ta~ <Rprofme~ <bch:~ <tibbl~
```

Comment: the solution works on the small dataset but when running on my 81 million rows dt, fails with Error in rep(Y, rep.int(length(X), length(Y))) : invalid 'times' argument

Comment: interesting benchmarking result, upvoted for it!

Comment: @iuliux, I don't know how to reproduce that offhand. Perhaps you can edit your question and add the output from `dput(head(x))`?

Comment: ran on a subset of my dataset, 23 million lines and got a different error: Error: cannot allocate vector of size 4434924.0 Gb

Comment: Yeah, that size data will need an alternative approach...

Comment: @r2evans, would you mind to review and doublecheck [my benchmark results](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68976854/3817004) on large problem sizes? The results indicate that your `mapply()` approach performs quite well for large problem sizes (and is only beaten by [henrik's approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68958126/can-i-count-number-of-rows-within-certain-values/68976854#comment121872436_68958126)). Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

We could use `add_count` with `between`:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
    add_count(between(value, min_val, max_val)) %>% 
    select(1:4)
```

```
    value min_val max_val count
1: 94.001   94.00   94.02     3
2: 94.002   94.00   94.03     3
3: 94.003   94.01   94.04     0
4: 95.000   94.98   95.02     1
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another option using `Rcpp` given the size of the actual dataset:

```
library(Rcpp)
cppFunction("IntegerVector betnRcpp(NumericVector v, NumericVector minv, NumericVector maxv) {
    int n = v.size();
    IntegerVector res(n);
    
    for (int r=0; r<n; r++) {
        for (int i=0; i<n; i++) {
            if (v[i] > minv[r] && v[i] < maxv[r]) {
                res[r]++;
            }
        }
    }
    
    return res;
}")
#same df as ThomasIsCoding answer
setDT(df)[, count := betnRcpp(value, min_val, max_val)]
```

Comment: tried it, it ran over the weekend with no end in sight :)

Comment: If you have 80million rows, you need to perform 6.4 X 10^15 comparisons. If each comparison takes 1ms, you will need 10^11 seconds to do this pairwise comparison even with 64 cores

Answer (score 1):

Borrowing from @chinsoon12 answer, we can sort the values and ranges first, so we can add some tricks in cpp code to skip comparison of out of range values:

```
cppFunction("
IntegerVector f2(NumericVector v, NumericVector minv, NumericVector maxv) {
    int n = v.size();
    IntegerVector res(n);
    int i2 = 0;
    
    for (int r=0; r<n; r++) {
        for (int i=i2; i<n; i++) {
            if (v[i] > minv[r]) {
                if (v[i] < maxv[r]) {
                    res[r]++;
                } else {
                  break;
                }
            } else {
                i2 = i;
            }
        }
    }
    return res;}")
```

Crete fake data:

```
n <- 8e7
set.seed(1)
x <- sample.int(n, n, replace = T)
a <- seq(0, n - g, by = g)
p1 <- data.table(min_val = a, max_val = a + g)
d <- rbindlist(lapply(1:g, function(x) p1))
d[, value := x]
```

Benchmark:

```
# to use new rcpp function we need to sort values in new vector:
v2 <- sort(d$value)
d[, id := .I] # add id column if we want to sort the data back
setkey(d, min_val) # sort data.table by min_value

system.time(
    d[, count2 := d[d, on = .(value > min_val, value < max_val), .N, by = .EACHI]$N]
) # 54 seconds henrik
system.time(
    d[, count4 := f2(v2, min_val, max_val)]
) # 1.4 seconds
all.equal(d$count2, d$count4)
# TRUE
```

Even if we would include time of sorting the data, this should be much faster. The real time of course depends of your exact data. I would suggest first to test on sample of your data, not on all 80e6 rows first...

Answer (score 0):

This is not nice but do the work:

```
dt[, 
  count := lapply(seq.int(1, nrow(dt)), function(i) {
    sum(dt[, value] > dt[i, min_val] & dt[, value] < dt[i, max_val])
  })
]
```