# R conditional count of unique value over date range/window

Tags: r, date, data.table

In R, how can you count the number of observations fulfilling a condition over a time range?
Specifically, I want to count the number of different `id` by `country` over the last 8 months, but only if `id` occurs at least twice during these 8 months. Hence, for the count, it does not matter whether an `id` occurs 2x or 100x (doing this in 2 steps is maybe easier). `NA` exists both in `id` and `country`. Since this could otherwise be taken care off, accounting for this is not necessary but still helpful.

My current best try is, but does not account for the restriction (ID must appear at least twice in the previous 8 months) and also I find its counting odd when looking at the `dates="2017-12-12"`, where `desired_unrestricted` should be equal to **4** according to my counting but the code gives *2*.

```
dt[, date := as.Date(date)][
  , totalids := sapply(date, 
   function(x) length(unique(id[between(date, x - lubridate::month(8), x)]))), 
   by = country]
```

---

**Data**

```
library(data.table)
library(lubridate)

ID    <- c("1","1","1","1","1","1","2","2","2","3","3",NA,"4")
Date <- c("2017-01-01","2017-01-01", "2017-01-05", "2017-05-01", "2017-05-01","2018-05-02","2017-01-01", "2017-01-05", "2017-05-01", "2017-05-01","2017-05-01","2017-12-12","2017-12-12" )
Value <- c(2,4,3,5,2,5,8,17,17,3,7,5,3)
Country <- c("UK","UK","US","US",NA,"US","UK","UK","US","US","US","US","US")
Desired <- c(1,1,0,2,NA,0,1,2,2,2,2,1,1)
Desired_unrestricted <- c(2,2,1,3,NA,1,2,2,3,3,3,4,4)

dt <- data.frame(id=ID, date=Date, value=Value, country=Country, desired_output=Desired, desired_unrestricted=Desired_unrestricted)
setDT(dt)
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This `data.table`-only answer is motivated by a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68958126/can-i-count-number-of-rows-within-certain-values/68958336#comment121872436_68958126),

```r
dt[, date := as.Date(date)] # if not already `Date`-class
dt[, date8 := do.call(c, lapply(dt$date, function(z) seq(z, length=2, by="-8 months")[2]))
  ][, results := dt[dt, on = .(country, date > date8, date <= date), 
                    length(Filter(function(z) z > 1, table(id))), by = .EACHI]$V1
  ][, date8 := NULL ]
#         id       date value country desired_output desired_unrestricted results
#     <char>     <Date> <num>  <char>          <num>                <num>   <int>
#  1:      1 2017-01-01     2      UK              1                    2       1
#  2:      1 2017-01-01     4      UK              1                    2       1
#  3:      1 2017-01-05     3      US              0                    1       0
#  4:      1 2017-05-01     5      US              1                    3       2
#  5:      1 2017-05-01     2    <NA>             NA                   NA       0
#  6:      1 2018-05-02     5      US              0                    1       0
#  7:      2 2017-01-01     8      UK              1                    2       1
#  8:      2 2017-01-05    17      UK              2                    2       2
#  9:      2 2017-05-01    17      US              1                    3       2
# 10:      3 2017-05-01     3      US              2                    3       2
# 11:      3 2017-05-01     7      US              2                    3       2
# 12:   <NA> 2017-12-12     5      US              2                    4       1
# 13:      4 2017-12-12     3      US              2                    4       1
```

That's a lot to absorb.

Quick walk-through:

- "8 months ago":

  ```r
  seq(z, length=2, by="-8 months")[2]
  ```

  `seq.Date` (inferred by calling `seq` with a `Date`-class first argument) starts at `z` (current `date` for each row) and produces a sequence of length 2 with 8 months between them. `seq` always starts at the first argument, so `length=1` won't work (it'll only return `z`); `length=2` guarantees that the second value in the returned vector will be the "8 months before `date`" that we need.
- Date subtraction:

  ```r
  [, date8 := do.call(c, lapply(dt$date, function(z) seq(...)[2])) ]
  ```

  A simple base-R method for subtracting 8 months is `seq(date, length=2, by="-8 months")[2]`. `seq.Date` requires its first argument to be length-1, so we need to `sapply` or `lapply` it; unfortunately, `sapply` drops the class, so we `lapply` it and then programmatically `c`ombine them with `do.call(c, ...)` (since `c(..)` creates a list-column, and `unlist` will de-class it). (Perhaps this part can be improved.)

  We need that in `dt` *first* since we do a non-equi (range-based) join based on this value.
- Counting `id` with 2 or more visits:

  ```r
  length(Filter(function(z) z > 1, table(id)))
  ```

  We produce a `table(id)`, which gives us the count of each `id` within the join-period. `Filter(fun, ...)` allows us to reduce those that have a count below 2, and we're left with a named-vector of `id`s that had 2 or more visits. Retrieving the `length` is what we need.
- Self non-equi join:

  ```r
  dt[dt, on = .(country, date > date8, date <= date), ... ]
  ```

  Relatively straight-forward. This is an open/closed ranging, it can be changed to both-closed if you prefer.
- Self non-equi join but count `id`s by-row: `by=.EACHI`.
- Retrieve the results of that and assign into the original `dt`:

  ```r
  [, results := dt[...]$V1 ]
  ```

  Since the non-equi join included a value (`length(Filter(...))`) without a name, it's named `V1`, and all we want is that. (To be honest, I don't know exactly why assigning it more directly doesn't work ... but the counts are all wrong. Perhaps it's backwards by-row tallying.)
- Cleanup:

  ```r
  [, date8 := NULL ]
  ```

  (Nothing fancy here, just proper data-stewardship :-)

There are some discrepancies in my counts versus your `desired_output`, I wonder if those are just typos in the OP; I think the math is right ...

Comment: Great answer, thanks! I was first a little concerned, turns out it obviously only works without error when `date` is in date format: `dt[, date := as.Date(date)]`. The math is (as always) right, I corrected the `desired_output`.

Comment: I don't fully understand the `lapply(dt$date, function(z) seq(z, length=2, by="-8 months")[2]` part yet. Why is it `length=2` and what does the `[2]` do?

Comment: Yes, `Date`-class, my assumption, sry. `seq.Date` returns a sequence with special intervals; if we use `seq.Date(..., length=1)`, then we get `z` unchanged, i.e., `"2017-01-01"; `length=2` returns `c("2017-01-01", "2016-05-01")`, where the second element is the one we want. Because of that, we use `seq(...)[2]`. (We're calling `seq`, but because the first argument is `Date`-class, it uses `seq.Date` under the hood.) Hope that explains it. Glad it worked!

Comment: `lubridate` gives ability to just do `date-months(8)`, why the `seq` trick?

Comment: Not everybody uses `lubridate`.

Answer (score 2):

Although this question is tagged with `data.table`, here is a `dplyr::rowwise` solution to the problem. Is this what you had in mind? The output looks valid to me: The number of `ìd`s in the last 8 months which have a count of at least greater than `2`.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

dt <- dt %>% mutate(date = as.Date(date))

dt %>% 
  group_by(country) %>% 
  group_modify(~ .x %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(totalids = .x %>%
           filter(date <= .env$date, date >= .env$date %m-% months(8)) %>% 
           pull(id) %>% 
           table() %>% 
           `[`(. >1) %>% 
           length
  )) 

#> # A tibble: 13 x 7
#> # Groups:   country [3]
#>    country id    date       value desired_output desired_unrestricted totalids
#>    <chr>   <chr> <date>     <dbl>          <dbl>                <dbl>    <int>
#>  1 UK      1     2017-01-01     2              1                    2        1
#>  2 UK      1     2017-01-01     4              1                    2        1
#>  3 UK      2     2017-01-01     8              1                    2        1
#>  4 UK      2     2017-01-05    17              2                    2        2
#>  5 US      1     2017-01-05     3              0                    1        0
#>  6 US      1     2017-05-01     5              1                    3        2
#>  7 US      1     2018-05-02     5              0                    1        0
#>  8 US      2     2017-05-01    17              1                    3        2
#>  9 US      3     2017-05-01     3              2                    3        2
#> 10 US      3     2017-05-01     7              2                    3        2
#> 11 US      <NA>  2017-12-12     5              2                    4        1
#> 12 US      4     2017-12-12     3              2                    4        1
#> 13 <NA>    1     2017-05-01     2             NA                   NA        0
```

<sup>Created on 2021-09-02 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Thanks, this also works well and the output is valid indeed.  `data.table` appears to have the speed advantage here though.

Comment: Most definitely the `data.table` approach will be very much faster! `dplyr::rowwise` is readable, but slow.

Answer (score 2):

Here is another option:

```
setkey(dt, country, date, id)
dt[, date := as.IDate(date)][, 
    eightmthsago := as.IDate(sapply(as.IDate(date), function(x) seq(x, by="-8 months", length.out=2L)[2L]))]

dt[, c("out", "out_unres") := 
    dt[dt, on=.(country, date>=eightmthsago, date<=date), 
        by=.EACHI, {
                v <- id[!is.na(id)]
                .(uniqueN(v[duplicated(v)]), uniqueN(v))
            }][,1L:3L := NULL]
]
dt
```

output (like r2evans, I am also getting different output from desired as there seems to be a miscount in the desired output):

```
      id       date value country desired_output desired_unrestricted eightmthsago out out_unres
 1:    1 2017-05-01     2    <NA>             NA                   NA   2016-09-01   0         1
 2:    1 2017-01-01     2      UK              1                    2   2016-05-01   1         2
 3:    1 2017-01-01     4      UK              1                    2   2016-05-01   1         2
 4:    2 2017-01-01     8      UK              1                    2   2016-05-01   1         2
 5:    2 2017-01-05    17      UK              2                    2   2016-05-05   2         2
 6:    1 2017-01-05     3      US              0                    1   2016-05-05   0         1
 7:    1 2017-05-01     5      US              1                    3   2016-09-01   2         3
 8:    2 2017-05-01    17      US              1                    3   2016-09-01   2         3
 9:    3 2017-05-01     3      US              2                    3   2016-09-01   2         3
10:    3 2017-05-01     7      US              2                    3   2016-09-01   2         3
11: <NA> 2017-12-12     5      US              2                    4   2017-04-12   1         4
12:    4 2017-12-12     3      US              2                    4   2017-04-12   1         4
13:    1 2018-05-02     5      US              0                    1   2017-09-02   0         2
```

Comment: Thanks, great solution as well, perhaps even easier to understand. Your output is correct, I edited the `desired_output` vector to correct for the typos.